# How to connect to POSTGRESQL database from a JSP page

Tags: java, postgresql

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL database but this following code produces nothing on the page any help will be appreciated.

This page is hosted in apache tomcat and a geoserver is already connected to the same database on the same machine and working fine.

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" language="java" import="java.sql.* " %>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%
try {
    String driver = "org.postgresql.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/mahaproperties";
    String username = "postgres";
    String password = "Apple123!@#";
    String myDataField = null;
    String myQuery = "select * from public.maharashtra_parcel LIMIT 1000";
    Connection myConnection = null;
    PreparedStatement myPreparedStatement = null;
    ResultSet myResultSet = null;
    Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
    myConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
    myPreparedStatement = myConnection.prepareStatement(myQuery);
    ResultSet rs = myPreparedStatement.executeQuery();

    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    int  totalColumn = rsmd.getColumnCount();


    out.println("<table border='1' style='border-collapse:collapse'>");
    out.println("<tr>");

    for(int i=1;i<=totalColumn;i++)
    {
        String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
        out.println("<th>"+columnName+"</th>");
    }
    out.println("</tr>");

    while(rs.next())
    {    
        out.println("<tr>");
        for(int col=1;col<=totalColumn;col++)
        {            
            Object obj= rs.getObject(col);                    
            out.println("<td>"+ String.valueOf(obj) +"</td>");
        } 
        out.println("</tr>");
    }
    out.println("</table>");

}
catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (SQLException ex) {
    out.print("SQLException: "+ex.getMessage());
    out.print("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
    out.print("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
}
%>
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: I dont know i get a blank page.

Comment: Geoserver is already connected to the same database is that a problem.

Comment: Don't do that in a JSP page. Use a proper connection pool and do the database handling in a servlet or a tag.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_nameI am new to this is there something i can look into kinda link you suggest, i just want to get a few columns with unique entries for dropdown.

Comment: A quick tutorial on custom tags: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_custom_tags.htm or at least use a taglib for running the SQL: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html